# pip install numpy pandas fails?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pip

Pandas depends on numpy and there is an [open build issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/507) 
 to install pandas dependencies. Regardless, any ideas why pip quits on numpy in the below example? Also occurs if using a requirements file.

```
$virtualenv /tmp/pandatest
$source /tmp/pandatest/bin/activate
$pip install numpy pandas
```

Then in middle of numpy setup panda setup gets triggered.

```
  DeprecationWarning)
C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc-4.0 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -m32

compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -     Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -c'
gcc-4.0: _configtest.c
/usr/bin/gcc-4.0 _configtest.o -o _configtest
_configtest
failure.
removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest
building data_files sources
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
Downloading/unpacking pandas
Running setup.py egg_info for package pandas
# numpy needed to finish setup.  run:

    $ pip install numpy  # or easy_install numpy
```

....and when testing for numpy

```
(pandatest)$ python
Python 2.6.2 (r262:71600, Apr 16 2009, 09:17:39) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Computer, Inc. build 5250)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

Comment: Have you considered EPDFree (www.enthought.com)? Otherwise you will need to debug why NumPy is having a build problem.

Comment: The issue was closed in version 0.7. If this problem still exists have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11797688/1301710). The only solution seems to be to first install numpy and than other packages.

Answer (score 0):

probably what happened is:

it couldn't install "pandas", so the numpy was not installed too.

pip works this way:

if you try to install more than one package and if one of those packages doesn't really exist it breaks all the installation, so as pandas could not be installed it doesn't install pandas.

there's a issue in pip to solve this, I gave a shot trying to solve, but is not that simple...

anyway:

try install each package separately.

1. try to install numpy (it will work).
2. try to install pandas (it
       won't work, but you'll be able to see why it didn't install)